# Laurent series for $\frac{2}{(z)(z-1)(z-2)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

![image: Screenshot of question]
So I think I am getting the hang of Laurent Series, but having a bit of trouble with one of the fractions for part a).

So I split this up in to partial fractions: $\frac{1}{z} - \frac{2}{z-1}+\frac{1}{z-2}$

I am unsure what to do with the last fraction for part a, as if I divided it by 2 I'd have |z/2|<1 or |z| <2 which is obviously not what we want.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just add and subtract $1$ for the last one and group them appropriately.

Comment: This is OK, since the region of convergence is the intersection of those arising from fractions one, two and three.

Comment: @Rellek So then we'd have |z-1| < 1, is that okay?

Comment: @user1337 Okay, I think I understand what you mean